# Are N snapshot listeners on the same query priced as a single listener or N listeners

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have multiple listeners using `addSnapshotListener`:

```
db.collection("messages")
   .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
      // ...
   }
```

I understand that the first query snapshot contains all the matching documents. And they are retrieved from the server.

**Question:** What happens when I call `.addSnapshotListener` again? Does it still make a call to the server for the initial batch, thus incurring the cost of multiple document reads again?

Logically, I don't see a need to call the server, since it actively monitors for changes so the cached documents shouldn't be stale, but it's unclear what Firebase SDK actually does while the costs could be significant if I call this many times (say, in SwiftUI on each navigation).

Comment: You can see what the SDK does by looking at the [source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Firestore).

Comment: @DougStevenson, yeah, I suppose, with decent knowledge of Obj-C and C++ one might be able to figure this out :)  Do you happen to know? Or have an idea of how to test?

Comment: Why would you call it again if it's already listening? I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @bsod, I was thinking that the behavior would inform how to design the system. For example, as a user navigates to and from a screen that retrieves messages, should I just call "addSnapshotListener` every time the screen loads, or do I need to design a singleton that constantly listens to avoid a first-fetch "penalty"

Comment: That's entirely up to you based on how your users behave and what makes sense to you. How often is this page being navigated to? How important is this data? If these are "core" messages (i.e. this is the only stream of messages the user receives and they're important to the UX) then I'd almost certainly add one listener (probably in a singleton). If there are multiple streams of messages then I'd reconsider. But what's your mechanism for notifying the user of new incoming messages? You must have a listener listening to something.

Comment: Side note: Firestore's snapshot listeners are apparently rather "inexpensive", according to what the devs at Firebase have said on SO. If you need 50 to run a smooth UX, then add 50. If you need 500, then maybe I'd reconsider the strategy because I think I read somewhere that 100 active listeners is the Mason-Dixon line, if you will—but definitely don't quote me on that.

Comment: @bsod, I was just trying to answer your comment on why/how you could call a listener more than once. I was thinking of building a combine publisher around it, and wasn't sure how to handle multiple subscribers. When you say "inexpensive" - does that mean in terms of memory/compute footprint? And by "multiple listeners", do you mean listeners to different queries? It's just that if each new listener to the same query incurs N-document read in its initial batch, that can be quite a bit more expensive than keeping a singleton (which might be the right thing to do anyway)

Comment: I understand now—when you add the same listener twice throughout the app. I'd be surprised if Firebase made separate connections for the same listener; if they do then that would almost certainly be changed in a future update. And when I say inexpensive, I do mean on the engineering side, not the cost side—your app won't be bogged down by a bunch of concurrent listeners. And when I say multiple listeners, I assume they mean to separate queries but IDK. But if you really are adding the same listener throughout the app "often" then the decision to make one static listener is almost made for you.

Comment: The question maybe should be something like "are n snapshot listeners on the same query priced as a single listener or n listeners?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that how the SDK does what it does is irrelevant as according to the [documentation on billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

So even though the SDK, on a second execution of the listener, may call for the whole result set in a of the initial batch in order to check for updates, you will only be charged a read for each document added or updated. Also, in a initial execution you would be charged for reading all the documents of the resulting query.

Also, as mentioned by @bsod in the comments to the question, although not described in any documentation, it is very likely that you won't get charged twice if you have 2 instances of the same listener running in your code, as they would share the connection to the Firestore, making only 1 execution of the listener, although this has to be tested.

That being said, ideally you could try to set a single static listener to avoid any unwanted billing.

Comment: I mean, that *was* my question: "will the cost double?" for a second listener, but I'm not sure how the quoted text answers it one way or the other. From my limited testing of observing the network traffic, it seems that as long as there's at least one active listener, the subsequent ones don't go to the network, so presumably don't incur costs. But wanted to get an authoritative answer

Comment: Just re-read what you said: "So even though the SDK may call for the whole result set of the initial batch in order to check for updates, you will only be charged a read for each document added or updated." - is this true though? I haven't understood it as such. I assumed that the first batch incurs a read for each document, then also for each addition/modification

Comment: I guess I did not express myself all that well, I basically wanted to say that on a second execution even though the SDK checks every document in the batch (which is a read), you would only be charged for the documents that changed. Will edit that into the answer to make it clearer, but you point is indeed correct for a initial call. As per your first comment, I could not find this information anywhere so it might need to be tested, but as mentioned by @bsod, it's likely that they don't make separate connections.

Comment: @NewDev I edited my answer to reflect the comments that were made, let me know if you have any more questions regarding that.

Comment: I manually tried it out by creating multiple listeners, and checking the count of reads in dashboard, and it looks like it doesn't charge even when listeners are removed, then re-added (which was surprising to me)